# Which airlines operating in Europe offer flight bundles?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, europe

KLM offers flights bundles that allows one to, say, buy 20 flights between two airports, or an airport or a set of airports or even any airport in country. You buy the bundles then you're free free to book the flights, subject to certain limits (e.g. you have to book at least a certain number of days in advance).

Which other airlines (both regular and lowcost ones) in Europe offer deals like KLM's?

Comment: Almost every network airline offers some kind of a bundle pass for its regular commuters. Off the top of my head, I know that (aside from KL), AF, AZ, BA, EW, IB, JP, LH, LX, MS, RJ, and TP sell these kind of bulk-purchase tickets. Some of them are not sold directly but only through specialist agents like OptionTown. Most of them are not stand-out deals if you are a bargain hunter but might save you a lot of money if you are the kind of person who often has to be at a certain place at a certain time.

Comment: @Calchas good answer; add it and I'll upvote

Comment: @Calchas nice Answer. Could you edit the abbreviations to the full names, like KLM for KL and Air France for AF, so that not everyone (who is not that much into airlines) has to go google it?

Answer (score 3):

According to user @Calchas:

> Almost every network airline offers some kind of a bundle pass for its regular commuters. Off the top of my head, [the following airlines] sell these kind of bulk-purchase tickets. Some of them are not sold directly but only through specialist agents like [OptionTown](https://www.optiontown.com). Most of them are not stand-out deals if you are a bargain hunter but might save you a lot of money if you are the kind of person who often has to be at a certain place at a certain time.
>
> - [**KLM**](https://www.klm.com/)
> - [**Air France**](https://www.airfrance.fr/en)
> - [**Alitalia**](https://www.alitalia.com)
> - [**British Airways**](https://www.britishairways.com)
> - [**Eurowings Aviation**](https://www.eurowings.com)
> - [**Iberia**](https://www.iberia.com)
> - [**Adria Airways**](https://www.adria.si/en/)
> - [**Lufthansa**](https://lufthansa.com/)
> - [**Swiss**](https://www.swiss.com/)
> - [**Egyptair**](https://www.egyptair.com/)
> - [**Royal Jordanian**](https://rj.com/)
> - [**TAP Air Portugal**](https://www.flytap.com/)

Comment: I changed Swissair to Swiss because of their grounding in 2002

Comment: I have checked prices more than once and I agree with Daan. This is more useful for price predictability than for good prices/bargain s.